# Rails acts_as_follower get posts of users I'm following AND my own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, posts

I've managed to scope my posts to just the users I'm following with the following code:

```
following_ids = current_member.following_members.map(&:id)
@statuses = Status.where(member_id: following_ids).order("created_at DESC")
```

But I want to also include my own posts and I'm having trouble accomplishing this. So basically combining that code with this code:

```
@statuses = @member.statuses.order('created_at desc').all
```

What's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out I needed to use push not flatten.

```
@statuses = Status.where("member_id in (?)", following_ids.push(current_member.id)).order("created_at desc").all
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull both arrays of objects and flatten them.

```
following_ids = current_member.following_members.map(&:id)  
@statuses = Status.where(member_id: following_ids).order("created_at DESC")
@statuses << @member.statuses.order('created_at desc').all
@statuses = @statuses.flatten
```

To see the list in one chronological list, call sort_by

so instead of

```
@status = @statuses.flatten
```

use

```
@status = @statuses.flatten.sort_by{ |status| status.created_at }
```

Comment: That way stacks all the statuses of users I'm following on top of all my own statuses. I want them to be mixed in together according to time created.